# Autogenerate CRUD actions for Rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I've been tasked by my company to create a REST API (ASP.NET) to capture data returned by our already implemented data component. Because of an NDA, I can't go into too many details about how it works, but basically, you reference a .dll, reference the class and will after that be able to use a huge set of stored procedures / views from it

```
ReferencedDataComponent rdc = new ReferencedDataComponent();
DataSet ds = rdc.FETCHvw_DataToGet(param1, param2, paramN, paramN+1);
```

What I need to do is to create a way to handle all of these views automatically on a REST API that I've already set up (working with one of the views). 
I've been looking around on Google for a way to automatize the REST API, but to no avail.
Does anyone here have any good examples / advice on how to approach this? I'd prefer to not have to hard code all the CRUD actions on the REST API for the 100 or so views / spus..

Thanks.

J

Comment: Code generators? Maybe T4 templates?

Comment: is there a pattern in the rdc.* methods  like   FETCHxxxx_DataToGet where xxxx could be diffrent "tables" ?

Comment: @Thorarins Yep, there is a pattern to it. 
Say: dbo.spu_FETCHvw_xxxxx or change FETCH to Update/Insert etc.
However I'm unsure as to how to dynamically create classes (to handle the data) / routing... :/

Comment: make a webapi with a routing like /Fetch/{TableName}/{param1}/.../{paramN} , then use reflection on rdc object to find method .FETCH<<TableName>>

Comment: Hmm, that certainly makes a bunch of sense. The only existing problem I can see is how to handle the data return data (if get). The current webapi I have uses a class with a bunch of members {get; set;} that are specified before runtime. Do you know of any way of setting up a class dynamically at runtime so that all the returned data can be encapsulated in a collection / class and furthermore json-serialized in an orderly fashion?

Comment: you have a dataset in your sample , you could transform that into json ie a list of rows form that datatable